# Octave use of interp1 function returns NAN

Tags: octave

I am using the interp1 function to resample (a,b) to (new_a, new_b).
I get NAN for the values of new_b.
a, b are row matrices.
Some values in b are zero. How to get rid of this? Because of NAN I am unable to generate the correct plot for plot(new_a, new_b, 'r*)

```
c = cat(1,a, b);
[s,i] = sort(c(1,:)); #Sort by the 1st row              
sort_ab = c(:,i);
sort_a = sort_ab(1,:);
sort_b = sort_ab(2,:);                                              

new_a = min(sort_a):0.001:max(sort_a);                                  
new_b = interp1(a, b, new_a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html:

> For the `'nearest'`, `'linear'`, and
>   `'v5cubic'` methods,
>   `interp1(x,Y,xi,method)` returns `NaN` for
>   any element of `xi` that is outside the
>   interval spanned by `x`.

Note that `'linear'` is the default interpolation method.

You haven't provided us with the values of `a` and `b`, but the above sounds the most likely explanation.